# What gas price should I set for my transactions to ThunderCore?

Tags: web3js, thundercore

How do I determine the optimal gas price to use when sending transactions to ThunderCore?
What if my existing code expects a gas price oracle REST API like ETH Gas station or Etherscan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fees for transactions on ThunderCore are specified using separate fields:

- **gas price**
- **gas limit**

(like on Ethereum).

## Gas Price

- Use the [`eth_gasPrice`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_gasprice) RPC call to get the moving average of recent price

## Gas Limit

- Use the [`eth_estimateGas`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_estimategas) RPC call to estimate the computation and storage cost required by the transaction.
- If you know for sure the destination address is a regular account and not a smart contract, you can use specify a gas limit of 21 KWei (21,000 Wei)